# using the midwest dataset and making a nibble using tidy verse

Tags: r, tibble

using the midwest dataset I was able to answer my own question for making a tibble

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to group by state and category, and remove those fields from summarise()
try:

```
  midwest %>% 
  select(state, category, poptotal, popdensity, percollege) %>% 
  filter(category=='LHR'| category== 'LAR') %>%
  group_by(state, category) %>%
  summarise(totalPopulation=sum(poptotal),
            meanPopDensity=mean(popdensity),
            propcollege=proportions(percollege))
```

Comment: when I do that it still does not give me the correct answer @nogbad